# How to plot a PCA plot of binary file created in R? It is logical in nature and has 0 and 1 as values?

Tags: binary, boolean, pca

I am new to R, and I want to visualize my boolean or binary data that has values as 0 and 1 for the absence or presence of a trait. how do I plot PCA or is there any other way to represent it for better visualization?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.